# Как Ричард стал Диком

Tags: этимология, английский-язык

Прочитала много версий о превращении имени Ричард в имя Дик. Ни одной убедительной. Может быть, вы знаете, как это произошло? Про нашего Александра, ставшего Шурой, все знают. Как это было "у них"?

Comment: Ричард - Ричардик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"У них" - не обязательно точное сокращение, уменьшительно-ласкательное имя может быть просто похожим созвучием: Ричард - Ричи - Рик (как от Рикардо) - Дик. Как от Вильяма - Билл, Роберт-Боб, Маргарет - Рэг, Эдвард - Тэд.

У нашей цепочки  Георгий - Жора - Гоша тоже такая логика - просто что-то созвучное.

Comment: это не созвучия, это дефекты алфавита, от рика дика, от роб-боб получить плохим произношением нельзя, а вот при помощи неправильного чтения  можно. буквочка  D, хитрая с двумя хвостиками, может читаться как Р и наоборот.  С William тоже произношением не получается, слишком по разному звучат буквы  W В,   Какой алфавит содержит такую букву, которую можно прочитать как B?
С GEORGe все проще, читается по французски жорж- жора,   гоша и гога из другой этимологической ветки  от марго и маргоши, сын этой тетки. которого назвали Георгий.

Answer (score 2):

Всплыло.
Это ответ на "боковой" вопрос, сама ветка почищена, связь с исходным не очевидна. 
Оффтоп, конечно, но не убивать же его теперь?!
//==============

> 12.02.2015 Добавлено пояснение:
>
> *К сожалению, из-за того, что были убраны многие "боковые" ветки обсуждения, мой ответ оказался подвешенным в воздухе. А все
>   объясняется очень просто. Некий персонаж провел совершенно
>   некорректную параллель между "Ричардом-Диком" и "компьютером-ЭВМ".
>   Пришлось дать небольшую справку. Ну не убирать же её теперь?!*
>
> //---------------------
>
> (Гусляр)

Умом Гусляра не понять. А история появления термина вообще занимательна. Пока в Киеве в пятидесятых годах под руководством академика Лебедева создавался самый мощный в Европе (он же по сути - и первый) компьютер БЭСМ, в Москве шла борьба с "буржуазной лженаукой кибернетикой". Поэтому даже слово "вычислитель" было под запретом, а компьютер стал "счетной машиной". Потом - ЭСМ. И только впоследствии - ЭВСМ и ЭВМ. Последнее продержалось до середины восьмидесятых, породив "персональную ЭВМ".

"Компьютер" победил только с появлением в России более или менее современных (на тот момент) IMB-порожденных "писюнов". Которые по иронии судьбы ознаменовали конец эпохи IBM - International Business **Machines**, в чем усматривается отнюдь не случайная параллель: машинами компьютеры больше не называли, ни в России, ни в мире.

Comment: Пишете чушь и надеетесь на наивного читателя, который возьмёт ваше лайно с лопаты и не перепроверит. Но всё было не так: https://zampolit-ru.livejournal.com/11456665.html -- вот ссылка на правдивое изложение событий без примеси хуторских страданий по имперскому прошлому

Answer (score 1):

Пустой вопрос. 
Посмотри словарь русских имён и их бытовые варианты. Там каша из логики, языковых процессов, вкусовщины, диалектов, историзмов...
Ричарда недавно звали Хик, потом Дик, но... сегодня нужна осторожность - слово широко! употребляется как эвфемизм мужского члена. Сегодня Ричарда называют Рич.